# populate js table with json data

Tags: javascript, json, html-table

can you please please help me with something? i'm trying to create a table based on the information i receive from an endpoint. i've managed to create the structure of the table.

```
<div class="available-movies-component">
      <div class="color-code-wrapper">
        <span class="title">Key</span>
      </div>

      <div class="table-wrapper">

      </div>
    </div>

const API = 'https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alex-cenusa/movies/master/movies.json';
async function getData() {
  try {
    let response = await fetch(API);
    if (response.status == 200) {
      let data = await response.json();
      return data;
    } else {
      throw new Error(response.status);
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
}

getData().then((data) => {
  const KEY = data.data.key.forEach((key) => {
    const LEGEND_WRAPPER = document.querySelector('.color-code-wrapper');
    const UNIT_TYPE = key.type;
    const KEY_BTN = document.createElement('button');
    KEY_BTN.innerText = UNIT_TYPE;
    const KEY_BTN_COLOR = key.color;
    KEY_BTN.style.backgroundColor = KEY_BTN_COLOR;
    LEGEND_WRAPPER.appendChild(KEY_BTN);
  });

  const TABLE_WRAPPER = document.querySelector('.table-wrapper');

  let col = [];
  for (let i = 0; i < data.data.movies.length; i++) {
    for (let key in data.data.movies[i]) {
      if (col.indexOf(key) === -1) {
        col.push(key);
      }
    }
  }

  const table = document.createElement('table');
  let tr = table.insertRow(-1); // table row.

  for (let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    let th = document.createElement('th'); // table header.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < data.data.movies.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);

    for (let j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      tabCell.innerHTML = data.data.movies[i][col[j]];
    }
  }

  TABLE_WRAPPER.appendChild(table);
});
```

and here is my jsfiddle https://jsfiddle.net/nopqxdvz/

what i need to do now, and i need some help with is to create a button inside every row corresponding to Type/Use column, with the name inside the object and for the background-color of the button to have the hex code inside the object. and for the Rental, to have a link with the href of the url provided if the url exists. right now i'm getting [object Object]

thanks in advance for every help i can get!

Comment: added solution @sleepwalker127

Comment: added exact solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https://jsfiddle.net/cjr6sfpb/2/ here solution

Code i changed added button styling :

```js
// added this mergeObjectValues function to handle.
let button_style= {
    "Comedy" : "blue-button",
    "Thriller":"pink-button",
    "Alternative":"green-button",
    "Documentary":"red-button"
  }

  function mergeObjectValues(key,obj,tablecell){
   let merge_string = [];
   let button;
   for (let i = 0; i < obj.length; i++) {
     if(merge_string.indexOf(obj[i][key]) == -1)
      { 
        merge_string.push(obj[i][key]); 
        if (key == 'type'){
          button = document.createElement('button'); 
          button.classList.add(button_style[obj[i][key]]);
          button.innerHTML = obj[i][key];
          tablecell.append(button);
        }
        else{
        merge_string.push(obj[i][key]); 
        tablecell.innerHTML = obj[i][key];
        }
      }
   }
   return tablecell;
  }

  const table = document.createElement('table');
  let tr = table.insertRow(-1); // table row.

  for (let i = 0; i < col.length; i++) {
    let th = document.createElement('th'); // table header.
    th.innerHTML = col[i];
    tr.appendChild(th);
  }
  let col_key ={
    "Type/Use" : "type",
    "Rental" : "name"
  }
  for (let i = 0; i < data.data.movies.length; i++) {
    tr = table.insertRow(-1);

    for (let j = 0; j < col.length; j++) {
      let tabCell = tr.insertCell(-1);
      var tablecontent = data.data.movies[i][col[j]];

      console.log(col);
      console.log(tablecontent instanceof Array);
      if( tablecontent instanceof Array){
       tabCell = mergeObjectValues(col_key[col[j]],tablecontent,tabCell);
      }else{
      tabCell.innerHTML = tablecontent;
      }

    }
  }
```

[image]

Comment: thanks a lot for this. i really like this approach. but how can i display all items  for example, in the column where i have comedy thriller, all three from inside of "Type/Use": [
          {
            "name": "A1",
             "type": "Comedy",
            "color": "#4000ff"
          },
          {
            "name": "A3",
            "type": "Comedy",
            "color": "#4000ff"
          },
          {
            "name": "B1a",
            "type": "Thriller",
            "color": "#ff00bf"
          }
        ], and the innertext for btn to be the name from object?

Comment: I did same thing if you have multiple it will show check fiddle

Comment: yes. what i mean is that in the column width Movies1 8 Let Comedy Thriller. in the type array, i have 3 objects. {
            "name": "A1",
             "type": "Comedy",
            "color": "#4000ff"
          },
          {
            "name": "A3",
            "type": "Comedy",
            "color": "#4000ff"
          },
          {
            "name": "B1a",
            "type": "Thriller",
            "color": "#ff00bf"
          } how can i display all three? in fiddle it's only showing 2 (comedy and thriller). and i need to be (a1, a3 and b1a)

Comment: Because I remove duplicate. Can remove if case

Comment: Remove if case at 4 line of mergeObjectValues function.

Comment: yes, thanks for the fiddle. but like i've said. i'm trying to get the name inside the type column instead of the type. for ex "name": "A1" instead of comedy. i only use type: comedy for the color legend above the table

Comment: don't forget to upvote and accept answer if this help you. @sleepwalker127. Like you said it can possible to do. Just change this line `button.innerHTML = obj[i][key]` to `button.innerHTML = obj[i]['name']`

Comment: you can upvote also you have enough reputation. @sleepwalker127 https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/41347/why-are-15-reputation-points-required-to-upvote